# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. 
When I try to include a .css file into index.html in my project I have an error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

How do I include a CSS file into index.html

Comment: I am following how to create forms from angular GUIDE. So to style my form i am just adding a link to the index.html as said in there . But i am getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Each Angular component has its own CSS, but you can add a global CSS file(s) if need be.

If you're using Angular CLI for creating your project, open the file .angular-cli.json and add your global CSS file(s) to this array:

"styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ]

Alternatively, you can just copy/paste your CSS code into styles.css.

Comment: I have added my file in .angular-cli.json but it's not working. But if I add that CSS into styles.css its working and still I am getting an error of  **GET http://localhost:4200/styles.css** in my console. Can i know why?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly mention the file styles.css in any of your code.